# error Tokenizing data using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using following commands to extract data from the github.

```
url='https://github.com/cs109/2014/blob/master/lectures/lecture02/wur2013.txt'
ranking = pd.read_table(url)
```

I am getting following error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 447, saw 15
```

As i don't want to skip any row from my data. 
I also tried using read_csv function but it is not helping me to extract the data correctly. Please suggest possible solution and if able , then please provide sufficient reason for this error.

Comment: Post the first few lines of the file, it's likely that it's not comma separated or needs more advanced parsing, hence the error

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with parsing via url, if you download the file locally and read it, it loads fine, can you try that and pass `sep='\t'`

Comment: As EdChum proposed you can always use `urllib.urlretrieve(url, 'wur2013.txt')` then read the file with `pandas`, and delete it automatically if needed.

Comment: @EdChum the link is open to everyone. Please go to it and you can see the whole data.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel following your methodology leads me to the same kind of error but with different line no.It says Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 104, saw 3